# Using image in place of Rectangle in Java?

Tags: java

It's my first time trying to create a 2d game in java and I made a little 8-bit like character that I want to put in place of the rectangle that appears on screen. I can't quite understand how to get the .png image into the rectangle's place, or how I would go about making the character, in this case, the image saved to my hard drive. Thanks!

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class Keying extends JPanel {

    public Rectangle character;
    public int charW = 24;
    public int charH = 36;

    public boolean right = false;
    public boolean left = false;
    public boolean up = false;
    public boolean down = false;

    public Keying(Display f, Images i)
    {
        character = new Rectangle(180, 180, charW, charH);
        f.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter()
        {
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
            {
                if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D)
                {
                    right = true;
                }
                if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A)
                {
                    left = true;
                }
                if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S)
                {
                    down = true;
                }
                if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W)
                {
                    up = true;
                }
            }
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
            {
                if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D)
                {
                    right = false;
                }
                if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A)
                {
                    left = false;
                }
                if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S)
                {
                    down = false;
                }
                if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W)
                {
                    up = false;
                }
            }
        });
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        this.setBackground(Color.white);
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect(character.x, character.y, character.width, character.height);

        if (right)
        {
            character.x += 1;
        }
        if (left)
        {
            character.x -= 1;
        }
        if (down)
        {
            character.y += 1;
        }
        if (up)
        {
            character.y -= 1;
        }
        repaint();
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process is relatively simple...

Start by loading the character image...

```
public class Keying extends JPanel {

    //public Rectangle character;
    private java.awt.BufferedImage character;
    private java.awt.Point characterLocation;
    //...

    public Keying(Display f, Images i) throws IOException
    {
        character = javax.ImageIO.read(...);
        characterLocation = new Point(0, 0);
        //...
```

See [Reading/Loading an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) for more details...

Then, you simply want to paint the `character` image...

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    g.drawImage(character, characterLocaiton.x, characterLocation.y, this);
```

**Advice**

- Avoid `KeyListener`, it's prone to focus issues you really don't want to deal with.  Instead use key bindings, see [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for more details
- Avoid putting any logic within any of the paint routines, painting can occur at any time, many of which you don't control, this could have your character moving in directions you don't expect or faster than they should.  Instead, this belongs within the main game loop which is responsible for updating the state and scheduling paint requests.
- NEVER change the state of the component from within any paint method, this could cause an infinite loop of paint requests, which will consume your systems resources.  Within your context, don't call `setBackground` (by the time you call this, the background has already been painted anyway) or `repaint`

Comment: Changed to what I gathered from reading the page on Reading/Loading an Image and what you posted. Received these errors :/--------------------------------
javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
 at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
 at test.Keying.<init>(Keying.java:28)
 at test.Display.<init>(Display.java:20)
 at test.MonGame.<clinit>(MonGame.java:7)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Container.add(Unknown Source)

Comment: Where is the image stored (relative to your project)?  What path did you supply `ImageIO.read`?

Comment: In the same package as the classes, the path was just the name of the .png image. I'm guessing I'd have to use like /test/src/(name of image)? Using `character = ImageIO.read(new File())` btw

Comment: Try using something more like `ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("name of image"))` (don't forget to include the image extension)

Comment: Yay it worked :D you're amazing! Thank you my friend